LSTM not learning with the label/answer literally in the features
In my code, I put the labels as the first feature in the first timestep, and the LSTM is unable to learn that the answer is in the first timestemp, almost like it is blind to it.
I ran this test because in my real data, my LSTM thinks some variables in the last timestep have no importance in the prediction, yet a gradient tree on the same data finds this pattern.
What's up with my LSTMs? They seems so poor.
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout, Bidirectional

test_length = 0.15

test_length = 0.15

#features = np.random.rand(1000000, 20, 20)
features = np.zeros((100000, 40, 40))
labels = np.random.rand(100000)

features[:, 0, 0] = labels.copy()

features_train = features[0:int(len(features)*(1-test_length))]
labels_train = labels[0:int(len(labels)*(1-test_length))]
features_test = features[int(len(features)*(1-test_length)):]
labels_test = labels[int(len(labels)*(1-test_length)):]

model = Sequential([
    LSTM(100, return_sequences=False),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Dense(50, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Dense(30, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Dense(1, activation='linear')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

history = model.fit(
    features_train, labels_train,
    epochs=1,
    batch_size=40,
    validation_data=(features_test, labels_test),
    verbose=1
)


Edit:
It was the Dropout (facepalm).
With dropout, the model can't rely on the one feature I am giving it that is useful.
Wow.

You can use StandardScaler() and increase the number of epochs:
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

test_length = 0.15
features = np.zeros((1000, 40, 40))
labels = np.random.rand(1000)

features[:, 0, 0] = labels.copy()

features_train = features[0:int(len(features) * (1 - test_length))]
labels_train = labels[0:int(len(labels) * (1 - test_length))]
features_test = features[int(len(features) * (1 - test_length)):]
labels_test = labels[int(len(labels) * (1 - test_length)):]

SS = StandardScaler()

TR = features_train.reshape(-1, features_train.shape[-1])
TS = features_test.reshape(-1, features_test.shape[-1])

TRN = SS.fit_transform(TR).reshape(features_train.shape)
TSN = SS.transform(TS).reshape(features_test.shape)

model = Sequential([
    LSTM(100, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(features_train.shape[1], features_train.shape[2])),
    Dropout(0.2),
    LSTM(50, return_sequences=False),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Dense(50, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Dense(30, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Dense(1, activation='linear')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5, restore_best_weights=True)
history = model.fit(
    TRN, labels_train,
    epochs=100,
    batch_size=64,
    validation_data=(TSN, labels_test),
    callbacks=[early_stopping],
    verbose=1
)


Note:
You can also pass EarlyStopping() callbacks.
